# MemoryError when use sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used DBSCAN to cluster the vehicle latitude and longitude data, trying to mark the abnormal clusters.
The data of csv likes this：

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_1
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:07:15+00:00,39.913597,116.193188,0.0,,0.0,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:07:45+00:00,39.913821528679,116.193375057897,0.0296303113263,,3.617864630805,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:07:57+00:00,39.913577,116.193185,0.06128788359619999,,9.486204442461,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:08:09+00:00,39.91355620681,116.19326818787701,0.0687502824682,,2.197516232255,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:21:51+00:00,39.91357,116.19316,0.07810475686389999,,0.0,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:22:13+00:00,39.913879261124,116.193598579289,0.2070232576078,,8.015839707631,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 04:22:31+00:00,39.913574,116.193173,0.33482624005330003,,9.984018532015,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 05:03:35+00:00,39.913988825593,116.193054292195,0.7641074298601,,0.0,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 05:03:36+00:00,39.913643,116.193119,1.028801941115,,222.354715722931,202009
00ad3c896ed6e733,2020-09-18 05:04:43+00:00,39.9138229035,116.19311423232,1.201805855002,,0.0,202009
```

There are about 1000 csv files, most of the csv is 50KB, the largest csv is 4.3MB.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

def testPlt():
    device_csv_dir = r'E:/device_csv/'
    for name in os.listdir(device_csv_dir):
        csv_name = device_csv_dir + os.sep + name
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False)
        X = df.iloc[:,2:4] #get latitude and longitude
        # convert eps to radians for use by haversine
        kms_per_rad = 6371.0088
        epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_rad
        dbsc = (DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')
                .fit(np.radians(X)))
        fac_cluster_labels = dbsc.labels_
        # get the number of clusters
        num_clusters = len(set(dbsc.labels_))
        # turn the clusters into a pandas series,where each element is a cluster of points
        dbsc_clusters = pd.Series([X[fac_cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
        # get centroid of each cluster
        fac_centroids = dbsc_clusters.map(get_centroid)
        # unzip the list of centroid points (lat, lon) tuples into separate lat and lon lists
        cent_lats, cent_lons = zip(*fac_centroids)
        # from these lats/lons create a new df of one representative point for eac cluster
        centroids_pd = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': cent_lons, 'latitude': cent_lats})
        # Plot the faciity clusters and cluster centroid
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[20, 12])
        facility_scatter = ax.scatter(X['longitude'], X['latitude'], c=fac_cluster_labels,
                                       edgecolor='None', alpha=0.7, s=120)
        centroid_scatter = ax.scatter(centroids_pd['longitude'], centroids_pd['latitude'], marker='x', linewidths=2,
                                      c='k', s=50)
        ax.set_title('Facility Clusters & Facility Centroid', fontsize=30)
        ax.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=24)
        ax.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=24)
        ax.legend([facility_scatter, centroid_scatter], ['Facilities', 'Facility Cluster Centroid'], loc='upper right',
                  fontsize=20)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testPlt()
```

This is the result:
[image]

I only drew 3 pictures and this error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/for_device_data.py", line 46, in <module>
    testPlt()
  File "E:/for_device_data.py", line 18, in testPlt
    .fit(np.radians(X)))
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.py", line 351, in fit
    **self.get_params())
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\dbscan_.py", line 175, in dbscan
    return_distance=False)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 747, in radius_neighbors
    for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 921, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 580, in _tree_query_radius_parallel_helper
    return tree.query_radius(data, radius, return_distance)
  File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1569, in sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius
  File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1525, in sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BinaryTree.query_radius
MemoryError
```

The CSV with MemoryError is special, it is 4.3MB.What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You run out of memory. Does this also happen when you run the code only on that one file where it fails?

Comment: The CSV with error is special, it is 4.3MB.

Comment: Just to be sure that no parallelization happens: set `njobs=1` in `DBSCAN`. Have you tried smaller values for `epsilon`? Have you tried using single precision for your `X` (`dtype=np.float32`)? The `DBSCAN` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) mentions some other ways to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `drop_duplicates()` to delete the duplicate data, and then there is no error. I think the memory error is caused by too much data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

def testPlt():
    device_csv_dir = r'E:/device_csv/'
    for name in os.listdir(device_csv_dir):
        csv_name = device_csv_dir + os.sep + name
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False)
        X = df.iloc[:,2:4] #get latitude and longitude
        X = X.drop_duplicates()
        # convert eps to radians for use by haversine
        kms_per_rad = 6371.0088
        epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_rad
        dbsc = (DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')
                .fit(np.radians(X)))
        fac_cluster_labels = dbsc.labels_
        # get the number of clusters
        num_clusters = len(set(dbsc.labels_))
        # turn the clusters into a pandas series,where each element is a cluster of points
        dbsc_clusters = pd.Series([X[fac_cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
        # get centroid of each cluster
        fac_centroids = dbsc_clusters.map(get_centroid)
        # unzip the list of centroid points (lat, lon) tuples into separate lat and lon lists
        cent_lats, cent_lons = zip(*fac_centroids)
        # from these lats/lons create a new df of one representative point for eac cluster
        centroids_pd = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': cent_lons, 'latitude': cent_lats})
        # Plot the faciity clusters and cluster centroid
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[20, 12])
        facility_scatter = ax.scatter(X['longitude'], X['latitude'], c=fac_cluster_labels,
                                       edgecolor='None', alpha=0.7, s=120)
        centroid_scatter = ax.scatter(centroids_pd['longitude'], centroids_pd['latitude'], marker='x', linewidths=2,
                                      c='k', s=50)
        ax.set_title('Facility Clusters & Facility Centroid', fontsize=30)
        ax.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=24)
        ax.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=24)
        ax.legend([facility_scatter, centroid_scatter], ['Facilities', 'Facility Cluster Centroid'], loc='upper right',
                  fontsize=20)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testPlt()
```